# Error trying to change value of a object within a list

Tags: python

Being:

Drawing, Segment an object

```
class Drawing(object):
    """docstring for Drawing"""
    def __init__(self, id, initial_x, initial_y, segments):
        super(Drawing, self).__init__()
        self.id = id
        self.segments = segments
        self.initial_x = initial_x
        self.initial_y = initial_y

class Segment(object):
    """docstring for Segment"""
    def __init__(self, p0, p1, type='LINE', attribs={}):
        super(Segment, self).__init__()
        self.p0 = p0
        self.p1 = p1
        self.type = type
        self.attribs = attribs
```

I want to change the values of attribs['layer'] to another value but it does not happen.

```
def _get_drawing_by_id(self, id):
    import copy
    for drawing in self.drawing_list:
        if drawing.id == id:
            d = drawing
            return d
    return None

function my_method(self):
    drawing = self._get_drawing_by_id(str(args[3]))
    for segment in drawing.segments:
        #print segment.attribs['layer'],
        layer = segment.attribs['layer']
        new_layer = self.swap_list[layer]
        segment.attribs['layer'] = new_layer
        print segment
        print segment.attribs
```

When printing last code, I get:

```
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cb10>
{'layer': 'LAY21'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cb50>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cb90>
{'layer': 'LAY21'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cbd0>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cc10>
{'layer': 'LAY21'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cc50>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cc90>
{'layer': 'LAY21'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177ccd0>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cd10>
{'layer': 'LAY21'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cd50>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cd90>
{'layer': 'LAY21'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cdd0>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
```

but later immediately I loop again drawing.segments and I get...

```
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cb10>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cb50>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cb90>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cbd0>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cc10>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cc50>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cc90>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177ccd0>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cd10>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cd50>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cd90>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
<cadstar.parser.Segment object at 0x7fbe5177cdd0>
{'layer': 'LAY20'}
```

as it was before the process of changing the value. Nothing changed!!!! And references are the same.

Updated:

swap_list is just a dictionary in this form {'LAY20': 'LAY21', 'LAY18': 'LAY19'}

Comment: `swap_list` does what? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Is your loop outside your method where you change the attribute? If so you need to `return` the changed dict otherwise the changes wont be known outside of the method.

Comment: @TinoA. Loops are in the same method. They still keep the reference.

Comment: @cricket_007 updated!